# Authentification works when browsed from Visual Studio but not with IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, exception, ado.net

I have a ASP.NET website. It's got a login page where I use built-in Membership class for user authentication. I've got a weird problem. In visual Studio when I point to my Default.aspx file and select View in browser I have no problem, I enter credentials and authenticate. But when I open the same website from the browser directly (localhost/MyWebsite)
either authentication fails or I get the following error:

> Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE’."

I use SQL Server express for Membership. I've put the mdf file in the App_Data folder.

Comment: Are you using Integrated Security = SSPI?? in your connection string

Comment: Yes I do use Integrated Security = SSPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using::

```
Integrated Security
```

In your connection string, then it only means that ASP.Net is trying to connect with your database using the **current AppPool identity** in this case, the *AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE*

You could change your database authentication mechanism to use a user/password and avoid this problem

Another solution is grant required permissions to the *AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE* user in your database